# Highcharts strange grouping behaviour

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts, zooming, display

I am using the [lazy loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) method to load OHLC data. On the server side I use Python + MySQL and have 4 tables with OHLC data and time intervals of 5min, 1hour, 1day, 1month. Actually it works well, but unfortunately Highcharts displays the candlesticks in a strange way. Especially at the initial loading and when I switch between the zooms. Here are some examples:

**1. Grouping on chart initialization**

On initial Loading `6h`, `24h` & `3d` is disabled and the candlesticks are wide apart.

[image]

Only after clicking then the first time `1w` the chart displays as follows, which is correct and also the zoom buttons `6h`, `24h` & `3d` are enabled now.

[image]

**2. Grouping when clicking between the rangeSelector buttons**

If I click then `All` inside the Range Selector I get the following display (this is wrong):
[image]

Only after clicking `1m` and then back on `All`I get the right display:
[image]

Does anybody know whats going on? Many thanks in advance! Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    function afterSetExtremes(e) {

        var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];    

        $.getJSON('http://ipaddress/data3?start=' + Math.round(e.min / 1000) +
                '&end=' + Math.round(e.max / 1000), function (data) {

            chart.series[0].setData(data);
            chart.hideLoading();
        });
    }

    //Initially load the biggest data range
    $.getJSON('http://ipaddress/data3?start=1481897400&end=1486910100', function (data) {

        // Add a null value for the end date
        //data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);

        // create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'candlestick',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },

            navigator: {
                adaptToUpdatedData: false,
                series: {
                    data: data
                }
            },

            scrollbar: {
                liveRedraw: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'hour', 
                    count: 6,
                    text: '6h',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: false,
                        units: [['minute', [15]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'hour', 
                    count: 24,
                    text: '24h',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: false,
                        units: [['minute', [30]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3d',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: false,
                        units: [['hour', [2]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 7,
                    text: '1w',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: false,
                        units: [['hour', [4]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 30,
                    text: '1m',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: false,
                        units: [['day', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 3    // Init loading button
            },

            xAxis: {
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes
                },
                //minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
            },

            yAxis: {
                floor: 0
            },

            series: [{
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add an example? Hard to say from just pictures, could be something wrong in your data or chart config.

Comment: @Piittis thank you for the help. See above, I added some code

Comment: Try to not share the same reference between navigator.series.data and series.data - the rest config looks correct.

Comment: Which reference should I use else? Unfortunately I don't get it.

Comment: Highcharts mutates the data object so you should not use it multiple times to load the data. Load a copy for a navgator and the original data for series - navigator.series.data = data.slice() and series.data = data - navigator and series will not share the same reference then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**1. No grouping on chart init**

To solve the grouping problem at the initialization stage, use the following lines:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    //.... your code ...
}, function(chart){
    chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(1);
    });
```

The problem here was that the selected button from chart options was not triggering afterSetExtremes event for xAxis.

**1. No grouping when clicking the rangeSelector**

To avoid Highcharts grouping the data when clicking between the `rangeSelector` buttons, set the chart as follows:

```
rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
        dataGrouping: {
            forced: false }
             }] }
```